# How to use template recursively in knockout.js

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

Given this model and view model of nested categories:

```
function Category(id, name) {
    var self = this;
    self.Id = ko.observable(id || '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000');
    self.Name = ko.observable(name);
    self.children = ko.observableArray();

    self.addCategory = function () {
        self.children.push(new Category("", ""));
    };

    self.removeCategory = function(category) {
        self.children.remove(category);
    };
}

var CategoryManagerViewModel = function() {
    var self = this;
    self.children = ko.observableArray();

    self.addCategory = function () {
        self.children.push(new Category("", ""));
    };

    self.removeCategory = function (category) {
        self.children.remove(category);
    };

    self.save = function() {
        self.lastSavedJson(JSON.stringify(ko.toJS(self.children), null, 2));
    };

    self.lastSavedJson = ko.observable("");
};
```

how do i make the template such that as more child categories are nested (and then categories nested within those categories etc) the template continues to be reused to reflect this?

At the moment my template is:

```
 <table class='categoriesEditor'>
                <tr>
                    <th>Category</th>
                    <th>Children</th>
                </tr>
                <tbody data-bind="foreach: children">
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <input data-bind='value: Name' />

                            <div><a href='#' style="color:black" data-bind='click: removeCategory'>Delete</a></div>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <table>
                                <tbody data-bind="foreach: children">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td><input data-bind='value: Name' /></td>
                                        <td><a href='#' style="color:black"  data-bind='click: removeCategory'>Delete</a></td>
                                        <td>
                                            <table>
                                                <tbody data-bind="foreach: children">
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td><input data-bind='value: Name' /></td>
                                                        <td><a href='#' style="color:black" data-bind='click: removeCategory'>Delete</a></td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                </tbody>
                                            </table>
                                            <a href='#' style="color:black" data-bind='click: addCategory'>Add cat</a>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                            <a href='#' style="color:black"  data-bind='click: addCategory'>Add cat</a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>

        <p>
            <button data-bind='click: addCategory'>Add root category</button>
            <button data-bind='click: save, enable: children().length > 0'>Save to JSON</button>
        </p>
```

which allow me 3 levels of nesting within categories, which is / will be fine for this app but what if I wanted more? Do i copy paste mark up for this? Surely not, I would think I've over done it already.

**Update:**

Binding is as follows:

```
  var viewModel = new CategoryManagerViewModel();
        viewModel.addCategory();
        ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

Comment: Dont worry, perfectly good question. I imagine the fickle downvoter was because your code is badly formatted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For a scenario like this, you would want to use a named template that you can call recursively.  So, you would have a setup (simplified) like:

```
<table>
    <tbody data-bind="template: { name: 'itemTmpl', data: root }"></tbody>
</table>

<script id="itemTmpl" type="text/html">
        <tr>
            <td data-bind="text: name"></td>
            <td>
                <table>
                    <tbody data-bind="template: { name: 'itemTmpl', foreach: children }"></tbody>
                </table>
            </td>   
        </tr>
</script>
```

So, you could call the template on a root note and then from there call it on the children (which would call it on their children, etc.)

Sample here: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/ex3xt/

Comment: Great stuff, Thanks. Perhaps a different question but is this supposed to automatically update when I dynamically change children? It doesn't at the mo but perhaps I'm doing something incorrectly or it's not supported.

Comment: Dont worry - I worked it out. In your jsFiddle you use visible: children.length as the conditional test for whether to display child templates. Perfectly fine there because you're using a plain old array as the type for children. However I'm using  

self.children = ko.observableArray(); 

which requires a function call to read the value so to make your fiddle work I needed to change "visible: children.length" to "visible: children().length". Thanks again.